# How to Print Different Text on Every page 

Tags: c#, printing

I want to Print in C#,

I Want to Print Some Random Data on Every Copy of the page user selected,

Is it Possible?

For example.

```
The User Select that he want 3 Copies of that page,

and on page 1 Should be printed =   123
on page 2 should be printed =       456
and on page 3 should be printed =   345
```

How is this possible, please give me some example

Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe you create three pages and with each creation you set the desired part(s) randomly?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a label a RandomNumber

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 100);
```

Where 0 and 100 is the range between which a random number is generated.